# kotlin using rxjava2 map operator to modify a list of users

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

```
Kotlin 1.3.31
RxJava2
```

I have the following method that should get a list of users and loops through using the map operator and increase the gpa by 10. Then print the result out in the `onNext`. However, what I am getting printed is this:

`kotlin.Unit`

I was thinking that the `list` of users should be passed down the stream to the `onNext` in the `subscribe` method

```
private fun getUserListMapped() {
        val disposable = getUserListFromCallable()
            .map {
                it.forEach { user ->
                    user.gpa *= 10
                }
            }
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.background())
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
            .subscribe { println("users $it") }
    }
```

This is what I am doing to get my users:

```
private fun getUserListFromCallable(): Observable<List<User>> {
        return Observable.fromCallable { createListOfUsers() }
    }

    private fun createListOfUsers(): List<User> {
        Thread.sleep(500L) // simulate getting from the network or local
        return listOf(
            User("john", "paris town", 5.6F),
            User("simon", "hollands place", 2.56F),
            User("lisa", "london bridge", 3.89F),
            User("peter", "tokyo hills", 4.3F))
    }
```

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: this is your return value in function `map`
`it.forEach { user ->
                    user.gpa *= 10
                }`

Answer (score 1):

in your `map` you have to return value:

```
.map {
    it.forEach { user ->
        user.gpa *= 10
    }
    it
}
```

or you can just use `doOnEach` like this:

```
.doOnEach {
    it.forEach { user ->
        user.gpa *= 10
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` method returns an `Unit` and that is why you see `Unit` printed. You should change the `map` operator to something like this:

```
   .map { it.map { user -> user.apply { gpa *= 10 } } }
```